# How detectors in particle colliders can differentiate neutrons from antineutrons?

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter, large-hadron-collider, neutrons, accelerator-physics

Their mass is the same. None of them interacts with EM fields. And their decay (around 1000s) is far too slow to see their decay products yet in the detector.

How is it then possible to differentiate them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Detectors at particle colliders are layered like onions around the collision vertex.

[image: CMS]

> The [CMS detecto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Muon_Solenoid)r at CERN

First there  are charged particle sensitive detectors where charged particles leave tracks because of ionisation, but mass density is low so  strong interactions do not happen often;  their momentum can be measured by the curvature in the imposed magnetic field.

Then there are electromagnetic calorimeters, where photons leave their energy and charged particles continue as tracks.

Then come the hadronic calorimeters with a lot of mass so that strongly interacting particles, hadrons, protons neutrons antiprotons antineutrons  deposit their energy.  Protons will have a continuous path up to the hadronic calorimeter due to their charge. Antiprotons will have negative charge. Neutrons will deposit energy without a previous track trace. Antineutrons will also deposit energy without a track, except due to the annihilation with matter the shower will be more energetic.

At LHC energies the difference in the multiplicity due to the annihilation for antineutrons will not be distinguishable. At low energies , antineutrons have higher multiplicity showers.

Generally in colliders the existence of antineutrons  might be guessed at by conservation of charge and baryon numbers, in low  multiplicity events.

Comment: Anna, how to understand „ At LHC energies the difference in the multiplicity due to the annihilation for antineutrons will not be distinguishable. At low energies , antineutrons have higher multiplicity showers.“  Do we have evidence or do we refer to Gedankenexperiments aka calculations?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Calculations are not gedenken experiments when the used data or predict data. The whole process of deciding what was the original particle that generated the signals and the signals of the produced particles in the whole sequence within the detector needs calcualtions and is very very elaborate. That is why so many physicists  are needed. It is not a simple bubble chamber event that is displayed from a camera and rough algebra might even give results in some cases.

Comment: Anna, I was misunderstood. Of course one need calculations for the results of such experiments. Your answer (not the comment) sounds to me like “we don’t find evidence, but theory tells us that it must be something and we have calculated it”.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler I am answering the title question. . Conservation of baryon number is evidence, within the standard model. A validated  theory  ( means agrees with data) allows us to encapsulate all the data fitted up to now in evaluating new data.  If discrepancies are found, the theory has to be modified, as has been happening continually in particle physics. It started with the Fermi model after all.

Answer (score 3):

The experiment which has measured the [most stringent limit](http://inspirehep.net/record/372023) on neutron to anti-neutron oscillations (i.e. produce neutrons, let them fly for some time and then look if you find anti-neutrons) has used a 130 micrometer thick and 110 cm diameter **carbon foil**. This target had a probability greater than 99% for anti-neutrons to interact (and thus produce secondary particles) and a high transparency for neutrons.

This target was surrounded by a tracking detector (for measuring the momentum of charged particles), scintillator counters and a calorimeter (for measuring the energy of charged and neutral particles). These are used to look for the products of an anti-neutron **annihilating** with the protons or neutrons of the carbon nuclei (while the neutrons would mostly only scatter elastically, i.e. leave the foil without breaking up).

Admittedly, the neutrons used in this experiment have relatively low energy, 0.002 electronvolt on average, corresponding to a velocity of 600 meters per second.

Comment: Please explain why there is a difference in interaction for antineutrons and a transparency for neutrons.

Comment: because anti-quarks in the anti-neutrons annihilate with the quarks in the protons and neutrons in the carbon nuclei while at such low energies, a neutron essentially behaves like an (unbreakable) ball

Comment: Quote from the link, you mentioned: “ No antineutron was detected in 2.4·107 s running time”.