# Proving that neutron and antineutron are not the same particles

Tags: particle-physics, neutrons

How can you prove that the neutron and antineutron are not the same particles knowing that neutron is not a stable particle?

Comment: I think we should leave this open solely because it invites "lateral thinking" experiments of great hilarity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How detectors in particle colliders can differentiate neutrons from antineutrons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/139540/how-detectors-in-particle-colliders-can-differentiate-neutrons-from-antineutrons)

Answer (score 5):

Fire neutrons or antineutrons at a beam target. The neutron scatters or maybe gets absorbed. The antineutron annihilates with a baryon, producing a very different outcome.

Also, you could just let your particle sit there until it decays, and see what you get. The results are obviously different and easily distinguished in e.g. a bubble chamber: protons, electrons and antineutrinos for neutrons; antiprotons, positrons and neutrinos for the antineutron.

Answer (score 1):

Take a bucket of neutrons and watch them decay, thus measuring the 15 minute half-life. Then shoot antineutrons at that bunch and watch them disappear much more quickly.